# Getting a part of the Image

Tags: java, image-processing, sprite, bufferedimage

I have a sprite image

http://spriters-resource.com/pc_computer/maplestory/sheet/21909

I would like to first load the whole image as a BufferedImage, and I found that quite simple.

```
BufferedImage image_ = ImageIO.read(file_);
```

now that I have this buffered image I would like to be able to slice and dice it. I want to try to write a function that returns pieces of this Buffered image

```
public BufferedImage getImage(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

But I have absolutely no idea how one would go about cutting the BufferedImage into pieces. What would be the best way to go about it, or what other ideas would you suggest?

Any help would be appreciated, this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first port of call should the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)...

Take a look at [`BufferedImage#getSubImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: This is quite embarrassing. I kept on reading, but skipped that on function. Thank yo so much!!!

Comment: @Quillion It's easy to to do ;)